# Create a torch::Tensor in C++ to change the shape

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

I have a tensor array, and I want to change the shape of tensor. I tried to use **torch.view**, but it raise an exception that "shape[1] is invalid for input of size 10000". Anyone can give me a tips for the error information?

```
int shape[] = {1,1,100,100};
torch::Tensor img = torch::zeros((100,100),torch::KF32);
torch::Tensor tmg = img.view(*shape);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C++` is not `python` so constructs like `unpacking` with `*` obviously will not work. Same goes for `(, )`, you should use object which can be "auto-casted" to `IntArrayRef`.

### Creating objects basics

[`ArrayRef`](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classc10_1_1_array_ref.html) is a **template class** which means it can hold different C++ types and `IntArrayRef` is an alias for `ArrayRef<int>`. This class has a few constructors (e.g. from standard C-style array, `std::vector`, `std::array` or `std::initializer_list`).

Both `torch::zeros` and [`view` method of `torch::Tensor`](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classat_1_1_tensor.html#_CPPv4NK2at6Tensor4viewE11IntArrayRef) **require this exact object**.

What you can do is:

```
/* auto to feel more "Pythonic" */
auto img = torch::zeros({100, 100}, torch::kF32);
auto tmg = img.view({1, 1, 100, 100});
```

`{1, 1, 100, 100}` is `std::initializer_list<int>` type so `ArrayRef<int>` (a.k.a. `IntArrayRef`) can be constructed from it (probably moved as this object is an `rvalue`).

Same thing happens for `torch::zeros`.

### Easier way for this case

What you have here could be accomplished easier though with `unsqueeze` like this:

```
auto img = torch::zeros({100, 100}, torch::kF32);
auto unsqueezed = img.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0);
```

Where `0` in the dimension.

### About libtorch

All in all **read the reference and check types at least** if you want to work with C++. I agree docs could use some work but if you know something about C++ it shouldn't be too hard to follow even into source code which might be needed sometimes.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am new to Libtorch from python, and I found very little information in docs (compare with python)。I think you are right, I should check types first and follow the source code when I got the problem.

Comment: How to create the Tensor in the same device of another given tensor?